# Avoid unwanted text from Octave's symbolic package

Tags: python, matlab, octave, symbolic-math

When you call `vpa` (from Octave's [symbolic package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/symbolic/)) for the first time, Octave produces some text on screen before outputting the actual result. For example:

```
>> x = pretty(vpa('sqrt(-1)'))
OctSymPy v2.2.4: this is free software without warranty, see source.
Initializing communication with SymPy using a popen2() pipe.
Detected Windows: using "winwrapy.bat" to workaround Octave bug #43036
Some output from the Python subprocess (pid 6680) might appear next.

OctSymPy: Communication established.  SymPy v0.7.6.1.
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
x =   1.0*I
```

Note that the actual output (variable `x`)  is the string `'1.0*I'`, as expected. The rest is not part of the function output, but rather text produced directly on screen.

That text doesn't appear in subsequent calls to `vpa`, only the first time after starting Octave. It doesn't seem to be specifically related to `vpa`, but to the way Octave communicates with Python to handle symbolic computations.

Is there a way to **avoid that text being displayed**? Or failing that, is there a way to temporarily **capture stdout** to intercept that text? For example, Matlab's [`evalc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) (evaluate an expression with capture) would be a solution, but Octave doesn't have that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option `sympref quiet on` has [recently been committed](https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/commit/ae8a15cd28792d9fce842d1c859b0e91ae08c79b) which at least suppresses some of the messages. Check `doc sympref` to see if the changes are already present in your version.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: Not included in my symbolic 2.2.4 yet. But it does look promising!

Comment: I have just checked Octave 4.2.2 with Symbolic Package 2.6.0 on Windows 10. `sympref quiet on` reduces the unwanted output, but still produces two lines :-/ On Linux Fedora it's better, it only produces an empty newline